RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (100x768 and 2048x768)
I am trying to find similarity scores between the encodings of the image and prompt (which is the label of the image). I am new to machine learning, I realise that there is an issue with some shape of tensors, but I am confused. I extracted the features of the image using the detectron package on github. But things are not going as planned when I am feeding them for inputs.
Here is the code and error. I am using all the latest versions, tested on collab and I did not use cuda. I only used the CPU for computation.
Code:
import torch
from transformers import VisualBertModel, BertTokenizer
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
from detectron2.checkpoint import DetectionCheckpointer
from detectron2.structures import ImageList
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

def load_image(image_path):
    return Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')

def load_detectron_model(cfg_path):
    cfg = get_cfg()
    cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file(cfg_path))
    cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.5
    cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url(cfg_path)
    cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    
    model = build_model(cfg)
    checkpointer = DetectionCheckpointer(model)
    checkpointer.load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)
    model.eval()
    
    return model, cfg

def prepare_image(cfg, img):
    transform_gen = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((cfg.INPUT.MIN_SIZE_TEST, cfg.INPUT.MIN_SIZE_TEST)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
    ])
    img = transform_gen(img)
    
    pixel_mean = torch.Tensor(cfg.MODEL.PIXEL_MEAN).view(-1, 1, 1).to(img.device)
    pixel_std = torch.Tensor(cfg.MODEL.PIXEL_STD).view(-1, 1, 1).to(img.device)
    img = (img - pixel_mean) / pixel_std
    
    inputs = {"image": img, "height": img.shape[1], "width": img.shape[2]}
    
    size_divisibility = getattr(cfg.MODEL.BACKBONE, 'SIZE_DIVISIBILITY', 32)
    images = ImageList.from_tensors([inputs["image"]], size_divisibility)
    return images, inputs

def extract_features(model, cfg, img, max_features=100):
    images, inputs = prepare_image(cfg, img)
    features = model.backbone(images.tensor)
    proposals, _ = model.proposal_generator(images, features)
    
    box_features = model.roi_heads.box_pooler(
        [features[f] for f in model.roi_heads.box_in_features],
        [x.proposal_boxes for x in proposals]
    )
    box_features = model.roi_heads.box_head(box_features)
    predictions = model.roi_heads.box_predictor(box_features)
    
    pred_instances, _ = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.inference(predictions, proposals)
    pred_instances = model.roi_heads.forward_with_given_boxes(features, pred_instances)
    
    features = box_features[:len(pred_instances[0])]
    
    # Pad or truncate to max_features
    if features.size(0) < max_features:
        padding = torch.zeros(max_features - features.size(0), features.size(1), device=features.device)
        features = torch.cat([features, padding], dim=0)
    else:
        features = features[:max_features]
        
    return features, pred_instances[0].pred_boxes.tensor, pred_instances[0].scores


def project_visual_features(visual_embeds, output_dim):
    device = visual_embeds.device
    projection_layer = torch.nn.Linear(visual_embeds.size(-1), output_dim).to(device)
    return projection_layer(visual_embeds)

def get_similarity_score(image_path, prompt, detectron_model, detectron_cfg):
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    visualbert_model = VisualBertModel.from_pretrained("uclanlp/visualbert-vqa-coco-pre").to(device)
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
    
    # Load and process the image
    image = load_image(image_path)
    visual_embeds, _, _ = extract_features(detectron_model, detectron_cfg, image)


    # Project visual embeddings if needed
    if visual_embeds.size(1) != visualbert_model.config.hidden_size:
        visual_embeds = project_visual_features(visual_embeds, visualbert_model.config.hidden_size)
    
    # Tokenize the text
    inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt", padding=True).to(device)
    
    # Prepare inputs for VisualBERT
    inputs.update({
        "visual_embeds": visual_embeds.unsqueeze(0),  # Add batch dimension
        "visual_token_type_ids": torch.zeros((1, visual_embeds.size(0)), dtype=torch.long).to(device),
        "visual_attention_mask": torch.ones((1, visual_embeds.size(0)), dtype=torch.float).to(device)
    })

    # Get the output from VisualBERT
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = visualbert_model(**inputs)

    combined_representation = outputs.pooler_output.squeeze().cpu().numpy()
    
    # Get the text-only representation
    text_inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt", padding=True).to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        text_outputs = visualbert_model(**text_inputs)
    text_representation = text_outputs.pooler_output.squeeze().cpu().numpy()

    # Calculate cosine similarity
    similarity = 1 - cosine(combined_representation, text_representation)
    
    return similarity

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    detectron_cfg_path = "COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml"
    detectron_model, detectron_cfg = load_detectron_model(detectron_cfg_path)
    
    image_path = "/content/images_data/frog.jpg"
    prompt = "frog"
    similarity_score = get_similarity_score(image_path, prompt, detectron_model, detectron_cfg)
    print(f"Similarity score between the image and prompt: {similarity_score}")

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-791b53e8c25e> in <cell line: 130>()
    134     image_path = "/content/images_data/frog.jpg"
    135     prompt = "frog"
--> 136     similarity_score = get_similarity_score(image_path, prompt, detectron_model, detectron_cfg)
    137     print(f"Similarity score between the image and prompt: {similarity_score}")

9 frames
<ipython-input-27-791b53e8c25e> in get_similarity_score(image_path, prompt, detectron_model, detectron_cfg)
    112     # Get the output from VisualBERT
    113     with torch.no_grad():
--> 114         outputs = visualbert_model(**inputs)
    115 
    116     combined_representation = outputs.pooler_output.squeeze().cpu().numpy()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1530             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1531         else:
-> 1532             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1533 
   1534     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1539                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1540                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1541             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1542 
   1543         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/visual_bert/modeling_visual_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, visual_embeds, visual_attention_mask, visual_token_type_ids, image_text_alignment, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    792         head_mask = self.get_head_mask(head_mask, self.config.num_hidden_layers)
    793 
--> 794         embedding_output = self.embeddings(
    795             input_ids=input_ids,
    796             position_ids=position_ids,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1530             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1531         else:
-> 1532             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1533 
   1534     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1539                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1540                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1541             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1542 
   1543         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/visual_bert/modeling_visual_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids, position_ids, inputs_embeds, visual_embeds, visual_token_type_ids, image_text_alignment)
    124                 )
    125 
--> 126             visual_embeds = self.visual_projection(visual_embeds)
    127             visual_token_type_embeddings = self.visual_token_type_embeddings(visual_token_type_ids)
    128 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1530             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1531         else:
-> 1532             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1533 
   1534     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1539                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1540                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1541             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1542 
   1543         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    114 
    115     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 116         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    117 
    118     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (100x768 and 2048x768)

